# Add values in Semantic UI's Popup content

Tags: javascript, popup, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using [this Popup](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/popup/#states-pinned) and I want to send some values to its content attribute but it seems do not work.

This is the code:

```
          cellRender={value => (
            <Popup
              content="some content"
              on="click"
              pinned
              trigger={<div>{value}</div>}
            />
          )}
```

it works fine how it is now but I want to have some dynamic data in content.

Tried different methods like ``` content=``this is the data: ${value} ``` or `content=value` but doesn't work.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to use curly braces when setting the content?

This component works fine for me. Give it a shot with your component. If it's still not working, please post a more complete example that demonstrates the problem.

```
import React from "react";
import { Popup } from "semantic-ui-react";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const value = "TEST";
  return (
    <Popup
      content={`This is the data: ${value}`}
      on="click"
      pinned
      trigger={<div>{value}</div>}
    />
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

If you're not familiar with this syntax, you can read more about JSX [in the React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx).